# Read a file and display it backwards

Tags: c++

I need to write a program to read all the data from a file and display the contents backwards in c++ by including this part of the code. In order to read and display a single character, be that a digit (0-9), letter (a-z or A-Z), symbol (&^#) or space

```
{
 char digitLetterSymbolOrSpace;
 cin.get(digitLetterSymbolOrSpace); 

 cout << digitLetterSymbolOrSpace; 
}
```

so bacically what I need to do is Prompt the user for the filename
Read the data from the file one letter at a time and store it in a string and Write a function to display the context of the resulting string backwards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Okay. What have you tried so far? What's not working for you? No use us suggesting something you've tried. It's a lot easier if you show your attempt so far and we help fix what's wrong with your attempt.

Comment: This is my code

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


void getFile(char fileName[])
{
   cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
   cin  >> fileName;
}

char readFile(char fileName[],char datas[])
{
   ifstream fin(fileName);
   if (fin.fail())
   {
      cout << "Error reading file: " << fileName;
   }
   int i = 0;
   while (fin.get(datas[i]))
      i++;
   fin.close();
   

   return i;   
}

Comment: void display(char datas[])
{
   for (int i = datas[i] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (datas[i] == '.' || datas[i] == 'd' || datas[i] == '!')
      {
         
         
      }
      else if (datas[i] == ' ')
      {
         cout << ' ';
      }
      cout << datas[i];
      
   }

   cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
   char fileName[256];
   char datas[256];
   getFile(fileName);
   readFile(fileName,datas);
   display(datas);
   
   
   return 0;
}

Comment: The description "by including this part of the code" is much too vague. There is very likely a useful clue in the actual description of the task.

Comment: In order to read and display a single character, be that a digit (0-9), letter (a-z or A-Z), symbol (&^#) or
space (' ', '\t', or '\n'), can use that code that I posted together with the question

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    string fn;
    cin >> fn;

    ifstream fin(fn);

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        /* for reading data character by character.. */

        string vec="";

        char temp;

        while (fin.get(temp))
        {
            vec += temp;
        }
        /*for writing data in reverse order*/

        for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            cout << vec[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

as per your question

"so bacically what I need to do is Prompt the user for the filename Read the data from the file one letter at a time and store it in a string and Write a function to display the context of the resulting string backwards."

Comment: No it actually failed the test. But thank you for your help though

Comment: provide a sample?? where its fails